# 'classList' is undefined when using setElementClass in angular2

Tags: angular, renderer

here is my code...

```
constructor(private loginService: LoginService, 
            private router: Router, 
            private renderer: Renderer) { }

@ViewChild('element') private element: ElementRef;
this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element, 'shake', false);
```

**it causes 'Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined'**

if I change this way...

```
this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'shake', false);
```

**it causes 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined'**

how can I set element's class again?

Comment: Where do you call this code? ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: out of ngAfterViewInit

Comment: and even if I do this in ther ngAfterViewInit it has same error

Comment: Can you reproduce it in plunker?

Comment: I am sorry, I might only reproduce tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the Dom elememt:

> component.html

```
<div #myDiv></div>
```

> component.ts

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') private myDiv: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.myDiv.nativeElement, 'shake', true); } }
}
```

Here is a working plunk: [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GEIHgi8zgmX9S5GpJyLJ?p=preview)

Comment: I don't know why but still have same error
I use 4.3.3 version

but if I delete .nativeElement
it has 'Cannot read property 'add' of undefined' error

Comment: I am sorry, it seems like not working in plunk. I will copy and paste in my code and check later. thank you for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

The issue I'm seeing in the results you're getting is that the component is not finding an ElementRef child component (the `@ViewChild` decorator looks for child components). I generally use the constructor to inject the `ElementRef`, not the `@ViewChild` decorator.

Try adding `private element: ElementRef` to your list of params in the constructor. This has always worked for me.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(
        private loginService: LoginService, 
        private router: Router, 
        private renderer: Renderer,
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'shake');
    }
}
```

This example will require you to update your class signature to implement `AfterViewInit`, which will have to be imported from `@angular/core`

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but can you please give me an example? then I can understand better

Comment: I have updated my answer with the changes you'll need.

Comment: but I how can I use some element? Viewchild seem like not working

Comment: @JasonSpradlin you have not specified any element to apply the class. This will never work.

Comment: Ah, probably correct.  It should probably be `renderer.addClass` not `setElementClass`.  `addClass` is what I'm using to accomplish the same goal in my project.